# Delphi Package Resources - EResNotFound

Tags: delphi, resources

Having already Googled for a solution to this, none of the suggestions work for me so either I've missed something or I've done something wrong.

I have a number of packages within my Delphi XE2 application, of which a couple of these packages contain RCDATA resources which are ultimately PNG images.

The control(s) which uses the resource(s) works absolutely fine in the Delphi XE2 designer - the resource is loaded and drawn as expected. When I come to run the main application in which the package/control is used, I'm presented with an EResNotFound exception when the control attempts to load the resource item:

```
handle := FindClassHInstance(Self.ClassType);
fPlaneImage := TPngImage.Create;
fPlaneImage.LoadFromResourceName(handle, 'IDC_IMG_PLANE');
```

And when the application runs, I get the following error:

> Project PinPoint.exe raised exception class EResNotFound with message IDC_IMG_PLANE not found'.

And if I hit `continue` in the debugger, I then get:

> Project PinPoint.exe raise exception class EPNGCouldNotLoadResource with message 'The png image could not be loaded from the resource ID.'.

I've tried passing all variations of handle into the `LoadFromResource` function:

```
fPlaneImage.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'IDC_IMG_PLANE');
fPlaneImage.LoadFromResourceName(GetModuleHandle('AppCore.bpl'), 'IDC_IMG_PLANE');
fPlaneImage.LoadFromResourceName(FindClassHInstance(Self.ClassType), 'IDC_IMG_PLANE');
```

Yet they all yield the same exception.

I was considering whether it would be easier to create a standalone package which contained all the resources and then refer to this from each of the other packages within the project, rather than each package having their own resources however I'm unsure as to whether this would actually work.

Please could anyone offer any advice.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, well, I would have assumed so except the resource exists.

Comment: The error message suggests otherwise

Comment: I agree but I'm at a loss as to why. I've exhausted the options others have suggested for this problem which is why I'm asking for help

Comment: The system tells you that there is no resource with that ID. Trust it. Do some debugging to work out why. One obvious explanation is that at runtime an out of date package is being loaded.

Comment: Hi David. Ok, so I've opened up my exe file in a resource hacker and low-and-behold - it doesn't exist. One thing I have suddenly noticed in my build window is a message saying `Duplicate resource: Type 10 (RCDATA), ID PLATFORMTARGETS; File PinPoint.res resource kept; PinPointResources.res resource discarded`. Hmm.

Comment: Trust the system. Distrust yourself! Anyway, sounds like you are on the trail and you'll get there with some debugging work now.

Comment: Thanks for the hints

Comment: @weblar83: `FindClassHInstance()` is the correct solution in this case. You want the image to be loaded from the package's resources, regardless of whether the package is statically or dynamically linked. So let the RTL locate the module that contains the package's resources, whether it is the EXE or a BPL.

Comment: @weblar83: Are you putting your PNG resource into the package's main `.res` file?  If so, DON'T. That file is managed by the IDE, and it can (and likely will) wipe out custom resources. They should be in their own `.res` file that gets linked into the package. The easiest way to do that is to write an `.rc` file that references the PNG file, eg (myres.rc): `IDC_IMG_PLANE RCDATA myimage.png`, and then use an [`{$R}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Resource_file_(Delphi)) directive to link the `.rc` file in the package code, eg: `{$R myres.res myres.rc}`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I was putting the resource into the package via the Project > Resources and Images menu. I will try your method of using a separate resource file. I had thought about creating a separate package for just the resources - what do you think to this, good idea or bad? At least it means all resources are in one place.

Comment: @weblar83: Bad idea.  There is no reason to put the resources into a separate package. They will work just fine in the component packages, provided you keep them separate from each package's main resource, and link them properly.  You should keep each component's resources in the same package as the component itself, to allow `FindClassHInstance()` to work. Creating a separate resource package is just more work, and potentially more deployment requirements.

Comment: Ok, thanks @RemyLebeau

Comment: Do you remember how you solved this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t even remember asking this as a question!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below `FindResModule` function to get the resource module.

```
// use fPlaneImage.LoadFromResourceName(FindResModule('IDC_IMG_PLANE'), 'IDC_IMG_PLANE');

function FindResModule(const AResourceName: string): HINST;
var
  LModule: PLibModule;
begin
  LModule := LibModuleList;
  while Assigned(LModule) do
  begin
    Result := LModule.Instance;
    if (Result <> 0) and (FindResource(Result, PChar(AResourceName), RT_RCDATA) <> 0) then
      Exit;

    LModule := LModule^.Next;
  end;

  Result := 0;
end;
```

In case it fails most likely the resource is "eliminated by the linker". It may happen for example when you create your own packages and you miss to add the unit with the resource to your package or application file. Just add the unit to the uses clause of your application.

I see no harm if you create a separate package for resources. It should work fine but it is not actually required. Just one small hint, BPL package is not required, you may pack your resources into a DLL